# Buffer Overflow problem

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, ctf

I have a quick question about a buffer-overflow exploit in a 64-bit binary. Lately, I have found some basic buffer overflow vulnerabilities. I hoped I knew how to manage it, but apparently, I don't.

Task code:

```
void vulnFunc(int x){
  char buf[12];
  gets(buf);
  if(x!=10) system("/bin/cat flag.txt");
  else printf("Nope!");
}



int main(){
 vulnFunc(10);
 return 0;
}
```

In this scenario the buffer is allocated AFTER arg, so even if I override buffer, I can't change "x" value. I checked under the gdb and after I put bunch of "A"s to the buffer, the stack looks like this --> 0x0000000A 0x41414141 0x41414141.....

Comment: Sorry for not writing actual question:) That was a 64-bit binary. I also thought that this is not vulnerable code but actually got solved by some people:(

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119956)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually write a question in your question, but, assuming it's x86, then the argument for `x` *must* be put on the stack prior to calling into `vulnFunc`.  On x86-64, it's entirely possible this won't be vulnerable, because `x` is passed in a register, so it's unlikely to be anywhere on the stack, unless it is placed there by a side effect of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the return address on the stack to return to 'system("/bin/cat flag.txt")'.